# Changing Date Format in Sharepoint DateTimeControl Visual Studio

Tags: development, visual-studio, asp.net, datetimecontrol

I'm currently developing a SP Project using Visual Studio. Apparently the default date format for `Sharepoint:DateTimeControl` is **'yyyy/mm/dd'**, by using **LocaleId="2057"**, I can change it to **'dd/MM/yyyy'** which is fine.

Is there any way to change the date format to 'dd-MM-yyyy' without any script?

Maybe I'm missing out on another `LocaleId`, I have tried **LocaleId="1033"**, the format is ok, but the calendar is not English.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dates in SharePoint are stored in UTC, which is most likely why it's returned in that format when you're fetching the date programmatically. SharePoint sites have regional settings where you can define the appropriate locale, e.g. English - United Kingdom (2057). Once you have set the appropriate regional settings for the site, dates in the user interface will be shown in the appropriate format for that region. Below is a list of LCIDs for various regions worldwide:

[2.1.1906 Part 4 Section 7.6.2.39, LCID (Locale ID)](https://docs.microsoft.com/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a)

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, you can set Regional in site setting. By default, SharePoint Online sites display the dates in US format (MM/DD/YYYY). You may want to change the date format based on the country you live in.

Click on Settings gear >> Click on Site settings
On the Site settings page, Under Site Administration, click on the “Regional settings” link.

[image]

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.